# Perform single action for every subdirectory

Tags: git, bash-scripting

I am using git to manage my repositories. it can perform action only to the current directory/repository.

I have directories structure like the following:

```
myRepos
 |
 --repo 1
 --repo 2
 --repo A
 --repo B
```

I want to perform single action on every subdirectory like this:

```
pushd repo 1
git pull
popd
pushd repo 2
git pull
popd
pushd repo A
git pull
popd
pushd repo B
git pull
popd
```

The subdirectories can be changed when adding removing new repos and the command like can be changed.

I want to be able to use the bash file like that:

```
git-all.sh commit -m"." -a
```

Then, it will perform "git commit -m"." -a " instead of git pull for every sub directory.

Any ideas how to manage that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for i in myrepos/*/; do pushd "$i" && { git pull; popd }; done` should do the trick.

> `for i in myrepos/*/`

`for` runs the following commands once for every directory, copying the path into `$i`.

> `pushd "$i"`

Temporarily `cd`s into the directory at `$i`

> `git pull`

Fetches repo from `remote`

> `popd`

Returns to the directory the command was run